# how to delete from one table where count less than?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

I use this query to find the number of occurences of a field from one table in another table

```
select t.id, t.tag_text, count(*) cnt from sms s, template as t
where s.id_template=t.id
group by  t.tag_text
order by  cnt desc
```

How can I delete all rows from template if they occure in sms less than 5 times for example? Which would mean if count is less than 5. I use MySQL.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from template 

where   id in
        (
            select      id_template
            from        sms
            group by    id_template
            having      count(*) < 5 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use having for filter aggregated result eg:

```
  select t.id, t.tag_text, count(*) cnt 
  from sms s, template as t
  where s.id_template=t.id
  group by  t.tag_text
  having count(*) <5 
  order by  cnt desc
```

and for delete  eg:

```
  delete from  
  from sms as s
  inner join template as t on s.id_template=t.id
  group by  t.tag_text
  having count(*) <5
```